# If $A \in L(R^n,R^m)$, then $||A|| < \infty$ and A is a uniformly continuous mapping of $R^n$ into $R^m$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Definition: for $A \in L(R^n,R^m)$, define the norm $||A||$ of A be the sup of all numbers $|Ax|$, where x ranges over all vectors in $R^n$ with $|x| \leq 1$. Observe that $|Ax| \leq ||A|| |x|$ holds for all $x \in R^n$. If $\lambda$ is that $|Ax| \leq \lambda |x|$ for all $x \in R^n$, then $||A|| \leq \lambda$.

Theorem: If $A \in L(R^n,R^m)$, then $||A|| < \infty$ and A is a uniformly continuous mapping of $R^n$ into $R^m$.

Proof: Let ${e_1,..,e_n}$ be the standard basis in $R^n$ and suppose $x=\sum c_i e_i$, $|x| \leq 1$, so that $|c_i| \leq 1$ for $i=1,...,n$. Then $$|Ax|=| \sum c_i A e_i| \leq \sum |c_i| |A e_i| \leq \sum |A e_i|$$ so that $$||A|| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n |A e_i| < \infty$$. Since $$|Ax-Ay| \leq ||A|| |x-y|$$ if $x,y \in R^n$, the statement is proved.

Can someone explain the how does the inequality $|Ax| \leq ||A|| |x|$ prove uniformly continuous mapping, and what does $\lambda$ mean in this context? This is from Rudin's book by the way.

Comment: What is $\epsilon$ in your final question? How does it relate to the rest of the post? Anyway, the last inequality you wrote shows that the function $A(\cdot)$  is Lipschitz continuous, and hence uniformly continuous.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I rephrased, please check my recent edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A=0$ then  it is uniformly continuous so I will assume that $A \neq 0$. If $\epsilon >0$ is given take $\delta =\frac {\epsilon} {\|A\|}$. Then $\|Ax-Ay\| \leq \|A\| \|x-y\|<\epsilon$ whenever $\|x-y\| <\delta$. By definition this shows that $A$ is uniformly continuous.

$\lambda$ is just any positive number.

Comment: We should probably make a slight modification of letting $\delta = \dfrac{\epsilon}{\lVert A\rVert + 1}$ to avoid the $A=0$ case

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say "similar," but they are related. For if $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, let $\delta=\varepsilon/\lambda.$ (Assuming $\lambda\neq 0$; $\lambda=0$ is the easy case.)

Then

$$\|Ax-Ay\| = \|A(x-y)\| \le \lambda |x-y|<\lambda \delta = \varepsilon$$

whenever $|x-y|<\delta.$

This proof doesn't depend on fixing $x$, so it shows continuity at all $x$ with the same choice of $\varepsilon$, and therefore shows uniform continuity of $A$.